# Newtonsoft JSON does not contain definition for 'Item'

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, web-services

I'm trying to get Json Object from JSON Array in my web service project... and  I'm getting this error:

```
Newtonsoft JSON does not contain definition for 'Item' ,
```

I also tried to use other functions instead of "Item" function but that's not working too

By the way I used a VB to C# online converter tool to generate this code ...

this is my code

```
 try
        {
            HttpContext context = this.Context;
            string strJson = "";

            JArray OrderItems = JArray.Parse(JSONString);
            //Dim IncrementalConnection As New SqlConnection()
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand IncrementalIdCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TheOrderIds DEFAULT VALUES; SET @AutoID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn);
            SqlParameter Param = new SqlParameter();
            Param.ParameterName = "@AutoID";
            Param.Size = 4;
            Param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            IncrementalIdCommand.Parameters.Add(Param);
            IncrementalIdCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int OrderId = Convert.ToInt32(Param.Value);
            conn.Close();

            foreach (JObject OrderItem in OrderItems)
            {
                string strSQL = "insert into Orders(ProductNumber,Name,Category,Price,OrderId,TableNumber,WaiterName,CashierName,DateAndTime,isActive,isCoocked,isPaid,isYesCanceled,ProductQuantity,extraQty,PaidDate,isDiscounted, DicountPercent, AfterDiscount) values(@x,@y,@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h,@i,@j,@k,@l,0,getDate(),0,0,0)";
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", OrderItem.Item("ProductNumber").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y", OrderItem.Item("Name").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", OrderItem.Item("Category").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", OrderItem.Item("Price").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", OrderId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", OrderItem.Item("TableNumber").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", OrderItem.Item("WaiterName").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", OrderItem.Item("CashierName").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", OrderItem.Item("DateAndTime").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", OrderItem.Item("isActive").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", OrderItem.Item("isCoocked").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", OrderItem.Item("isPaid").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k", OrderItem.Item("isYesCanceled").ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", OrderItem.Item("ProductQuantity").ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            //ProductNumber As [String], Name As [String], Category As [String], Price As [String], OrderId As [String]'
            //this is the bridge to database\

            string json = "{\"result\":\"1\", \"exception\":" + "" + "\"" + "NULL" + "\"" + "\"}";
            context.Response.Write(strJson);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string json = "{\"result\":\"0\", \"exception\":" + "" + ex.Message + "\"}";
            Context.Response.Write(json); 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c#, one accesses an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) of a object simply by adding `[]` in the same way one accesses the elements of a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) has an indexer that takes a string and returns the property value of that name.  Thus you need to do:

```
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x", OrderItem["ProductNumber"].ToString());
```

And similarly for the other calls to `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()`.